# Why is my draw method not called in a subclassed MTKView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, metal

I'm trying to draw into a view subclassed from `MTKView`, but drawing methods are not being called.

```
@interface GameViewController : MTKView
@end

@implementation GameViewController
{
   ...
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"drawRect\n");
}

- (void)draw:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"draw\n");
}
```

None of the logged methods are being called. Why?

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalkit/mtkview?language=objc) I should either use a delegate or subclass `MTKView`. I chose subclassing because my understanding is that I can use keyboard input with it, which is what I want.

Comment: Are you sure you're instantiating an instance of your class as the view? Has it been added to a window that's showing? Two other things: 1) the type of the `rect` parameter of `-drawRect:` is `NSRect`, not `CGRect`, on macOS. 2) The `-draw` method of `MTKView` takes no parameter. Your `-draw:` method is unrelated and won't be called by the frameworks.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks. fixing 2) solved the issue. If you post it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have implemented a `-draw:` method. That is **not** an override of any method of `MTKView`. `MTKView` has a `-draw` method that takes no parameters. You need to change your method's signature if you intended to override that method.

That said, overriding `-draw` to log a message and then call through to the superclass implementation is reasonable, but you're not supposed to override it to do the actual drawing. The `-drawRect:` method should be overridden for that purpose. I don't know why your override of that method wasn't being called (although you did get the parameter type wrong).